# Toast vs Disk Util?

Tags: mac, mac-osx, backup-restoration, disk-image

I have several users that are insisting on the purchase of Toast. They will be using it to make backups of disks at possibly re-burn them if needed. I have used Disk Utility for that function. At this point there is no addition functionality needed. However, that can always change in the future. Is there any advantages or disadvantages to either solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disk Util is not as user friendly as Toast IMHO.

Try [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net) under the hood it uses the same utilites as disk util, but much more popular with the ladies.

Answer (score 2):

The only advantages of Toast of which I am aware are:

1. It has support for burning BluRay
   video
2. It mounts disc images in a
   way which is better suited to using pirated software

Neither reason is likely relevant to your business.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the advantage of DiskUtil is that it's free and currently does everything you need it to. The disdavantage is that the users don't like it (fair enough, it's not very friendly).

The advantages of Toast are that the users will be happy and if their requirements change in the future, Toast is good for just about any burning task a Mac User can throw at it. The disadvantage is that it costs money.

My advice is to compare the cost of the licenses for Toast with the cost of the time you will spend doing DiskUtil support for grumpy users, and pick the cheaper!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I tryed to get the users to use disk util, but I was getting complaints all the time, so it was cheaper to buy toast for them and not have to deal with re training them every week

Answer (score 0):

For just creating and burning ISOs, I would recommend using the Disk Utility (or Burn, as Nick Kavadias recommends). Toast basically duplicates functionality that already exists in OSX (i.e Disk Utility, iTunes, iMovie, iDVD) and charges you $80 for it.  Granted, it has a slick, all-in-one GUI, but a little bit of training in Disk Util should be sufficient for your users.